# Java JBoss naming displaying all values

Tags: java, jboss

I have been searching for a while, but I could found any informations if it is possible to list all custom configured namings on JBoss application server. Currently I'm using JBoss EAP 6.

In standalone.xml I configured naming like:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
    <bindings>
        <simple name="val1" value="test1"/>
        <simple name="var2" value="test2"/>
    </bindings>
</subsystem>
```

Is it possible in JavaEE to use Context and list all key/pair values of configured property in standalone dinamically?

Regards,
Dahakka

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Jndi lookup can be used like:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> namedEnum = initCtx.list("java:global/");

while (namedEnum.hasMore()) {
    System.out.println(namedEnum.next().getName());
}
```